# Problems migrating ASP.NET Core Identity from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on migrating my ASP.NET Core project from using Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL now that the MySQL DB provider has been released("pre-released").  I was using Core Identity for membership when using SQL Server and it worked in that configuration.  When I migrated the DB to MySQL (using the migration wizard in MySQL Workbench), I began receiving this error when saving a new user to the DB:

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Property'

The error comes in this code when executing the CreateAsync method:

```
public IActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
            user.UserName = obj.Username;
            user.Email = obj.Email;

            IdentityResult result = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, obj.Password).Result;
         }
    }
```

Here is my DbContext class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace PilotMaltApiCore.Models
{
   public class PilotDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
   {
       public PilotDbContext(DbContextOptions<PilotDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
           //nothing here
       }

       public DbSet<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Bag> Bags { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Variety> Varieties { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I was thinking it may have something to do with the difference in datatypes between SQL Server and MySQL.  Here is the SQL Server table:

[image]

And here is the MySQL table after using the migration wizard in MySQL Workbench:
[image]

Keep in mind, all of the code worked fine when using SQL Server. Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the charset for the varchar fields to utf8mb4 which fixed the issue.

I also chose to use Sapient Guardian's version of the MySql provider for .net Core and which has proved much less problematic than MySql's version.  It can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/SapientGuardian/SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial worked well for me:

http://blog.developers.ba/asp-net-identity-2-1-for-mysql/